# extract variable and data from a string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, perl

I'm manipulating perl hash into a python string. 
the new python string contains variables and data as below example:

```
"Task = [
     {hash: 1},
     {hash:2,
     b:5}
     ],
another_variable = [a
    b]"
```

I need to get only the first variable (Task) into a python variable (should end up with list of dicts).
trying to run eval command but with no luck (gives me SyntaxError: invalid syntax on the string).

what is the proper why to extract variable + data from the string?

note: I cannot write anything to the work area.

Comment: Provide working piece of code with current output and expected output.

Comment: Can you convert your string variable to have only one variable instead of multiple ?

Comment: There is no working code. I want to be able to access 'Task' list from within the script. I do not control the number of defined variables in the string.

Comment: Your format seems very similar to JSON (except for the `=` signs which should be `:`). Have you tried encoding the string as JSON?

Comment: encoding to JSON and then back to pythn dict worked. I've done some string replacement to make it work as you said. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to manipulate a Perl hash into a "python variable string", you can just use a JSON library to dump your hash as a JSON and then read this object in Python.

In Perl :

```
use JSON;
$task = { "a" => 1,
"b" => 2,
"c" => [1,2,3],
};
$json = JSON->new->allow_nonref;
$task_json_obj = $json->encode( $task );
```

You can pass the above JSON object to Python.

In Python :

```
import json

task = json.loads(json_string)
```

You can pass scalars, hashes, etc. in a standardised way using JSON.